# New bike chain for my mountain bike

Tags: chain

I have a hardtail mountain bike and recently I broke the 4 year old chain that I had on it. I’m looking for a new one and I’m wondering how many links I need for a 3x9(27 speed) bike.

Comment: Replacement chains generally come in one (long) length, and then you cut the chain to make it shorter.  There are undoubtedly several videos on Youtube to show you how to do this.

Comment: Same amount as the old chain?

Comment: @Michiel is correct. Bicycle chains don't differ in how long each link is. You can put the two chains side by side, and cut the new one to the same length. Michiel, since that is an answer, you should simply write it as an answer.

Comment: @WeiwenNg That makes the assumption the old chain was sized properly.

Comment: Check your cassette and chainrings for shark toothyness. A drive train with 4 years use is likely to need new cassette/freewheel and chainrings at the same time.

Comment: I would add measure it next to the old chain and make it the same number of links not the same length. As the chain wears the number of links remain the same but the chain length increases due to wear of the pins and barrels.

Answer (score 0):

Any bike chain you get will have enough links. The only thing to keep an eye on is the number of speeds it is for, which is the chain width. Just make sure you get a 9 speed chain.

There will be a range of lengths of chain that will technically work. A chain is too short if it can not reach around the big cogs on the front and back at the same time. You don't actually want to ever ride like that, but you don't want to break anything by just shifting into the wrong gear combo. A chain is too long if the deraileur can not take up all the slack when you are in both small cogs, or if the chain rubs up against itself because the rear pulley is too far back. Again, you don't want to go around riding in both small cogs, but if the chain becomes slack it can easily slap about and fall off.

The size of the range that will work depends on the difference in cost sizes your gears have, and the length of the derailleur cage. Mountain bikes generally have long-caged derailleurs to accommodate a wider range of cog sizes.

Often, the standard 114 link or so chain is an appropriate size for a mountain bike. If you put it on and it is not too long, you are good to go. But if you are really persnickity you might want to consider whether you want to be closer to too long or closer to too short.

If you are closer to being too short, the chain will actually be under more tension because the deraileur will be slightly more tight at any point than if the chain were longer. Tension in a spring increases as the spring is compressed. If the chain is more tight, it is less likely to bounce off the chainring. So if the terrain is very rough, you might benefit from a tighter chain.

On the other hand, if the chain is closer to being too long, you will be able to easily take a link out of necessary. Often if you break a chain the easiest way to fix it is to just remove a link and reconnect it. If you have sized your chain on the long side, this will be no problem.

As a side note, this is also why it is generally unreliable to just measure a new chain against the old one unless you know for sure that it was sized correctly and never had links removed.